# Animation stopping after using "prependTo()?"

Tags: jquery, animation, carousel

I've been working on a `jQuery carousel` for quite some time. All along the way I've been asking questions to get to the next step, and you all have been very helpful. I can see the light at the end of the tunnel of my first jQuery adventure, this should be the last step.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkQRM/)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var stage = $(".gallery");
var stageoffset = stage.offset();
var stageleft = stageoffset.left + 600;
var firstimage = $("img:eq(1)");
var lastimage = $("img:last");

function gallery () {
    firstimage.animate({"margin-left":"+=100px"}, {duration: 1000, easing: "linear", progress: checkBox});
};
var interv = setInterval(gallery, 1000);

function checkBox () {   
    if(!(typeof lastimage.offset() === 'undefined')) {
        var imageoffset = lastimage.offset();
        var imageleft = imageoffset.left;
        if(imageleft > stageleft) {
            lastimage.prependTo(firstimage);
            firstimage = lastimage;
            lastimage = lastimage.prev();
        };
    } else {
        clearInterval(interv);
    };
};
});
```

As you can see, thanks to you guys, the function to check if the images are outside of the stage  works perfectly. When this triggers, I try to take the first image and use "PrependTo" to take that image, and reinsert it at the front of the line.

Now, since the actual first image is what was the last image, I set the "firstimage" variable to the new first image. I then set the new last image using "lastimage.prev()."

However, as you can see on the JSFiddle, the animation halts after the original last image has been prepended to the original first image. How do I make the animation continue to flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have added comments as well for your reference to the logic that has been implemented

Check the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rachit_doshi/APpyM/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var img = [];
// Create images array to be looped through
img[0] = '<img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" id ="image" class="image" alt=""/>';
img[1] = '<img src="Jellyfish.jpg" id="image-two" class="image" alt=""/>';
img[2] = '<img src="Koala.jpg" id="image-three" class="image" alt=""/>';

// Counter for looping through img array
var i = 0;

var stage = $(".gallery");
stage.append(img[i]);
var secondimage = null;
var firstimage = $("img:eq(0)");
firstimage.css('margin-left', -firstimage.width());
function gallery() {
    // Since we need to show to images at a certain point of time and to move both the images i have used, firstimage and secondimage
    if (firstimage !== null) {
        // If firstimage is set animate that
        firstimage.animate({"margin-left": "+=100px"}, {duration: 1000, easing: "linear", progress: checkBox});

    }
    if (secondimage !== null) {
        // If secondimage is set animate that
        secondimage.animate({"margin-left": "+=100px"}, {duration: 1000, easing: "linear", progress: checkBox});
    }
}
var interv = setInterval(gallery, 1000);

function checkBox() {
    // If first image is not null and second is null and first image is about to move out of div, 
    // set second image as another iteration of img variable, once it moves out it is set as null
    // If second image is not null and first is null and second image is about to move out of div,
    // set first image as another iteration of img variable, once it moves out it is set as null
    // Finally, if all the iterations are set, then set i as -1 i.e. reset counter
    if ((secondimage === null && firstimage !== null && parseInt(firstimage.css('margin-left')) > parseInt(stage.width() / 3))
            || (firstimage === null && secondimage !== null && parseInt(secondimage.css('margin-left')) > parseInt(stage.width() / 3)) || (i === -1)) {
        i += 1;
        if (i < img.length) {
            stage.prepend(img[i]);
            $("img:eq(0)").css('margin-left', -$("img:eq(0)").width());
            if (secondimage === null) {
                secondimage = $("img:eq(0)");
            } else {
                firstimage = $("img:eq(0)");
            }
        } else {
            i = -1;
        }
    } else if (firstimage !== null && (parseInt(firstimage.css('margin-left')) > parseInt(stage.width()))) {
        // remove first image
        firstimage.remove();
        firstimage = null;
    } else if (secondimage !== null && (parseInt(secondimage.css('margin-left')) > parseInt(stage.width()))) {
        // remove second image
        secondimage.remove();
        secondimage = null;
    }

}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The end result is choppy, and I would rather restart completely than have an inferior product.

If the image is prepended to the list, why can't the animation be applied to the new first image, and have that image push the rest just like the original first image? Perhaps I simply need to stop the animation when it is prepended, and then restart it with the new parameters?

Comment: There are seamless endless jQuery sliders all over the internet, so there must be a way to accomplish the effect.

Comment: Yes there surely is, but then you cant just use it by moving the first element, i guess you have to move all the images individually so as to achieve the same, i can try and help you achieve the same if you want

Comment: Also the animation is not being applied to new first image is since, the variable firstimage holds the original first image and not the first image after being updated

Comment: Hmm. I have tried effecting all of the images, and I get dissimilar speeds, for some reason. Applying the same animation gets different speeds on the images. 

Hmm, shouldn't setting the variable "firstimage" to what was originally the "lastimage" which was prepended to the list, before setting "lastimage" as the new "lastimage" work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33470/discussion-between-allenph-and-rachit-doshi)

Comment: i am trying to make a fiddle for the same way you want it will post once done

Comment: Well, thanks for your dedication, not expected, but greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Finally Got what you needed, have updated in the answer please check that url

Comment: Thank you so much! A great solution! Also, thanks for adding the comments so that I could not only use the code, but understand it. Excellent! You're a gentleman and a scholar. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... i forgot to remove the elements from the DOM, so i am re-updating the answer, please check that